# Getting same result When accessing Plain Array and Collection Array in Laravel upgrade 5.2 to 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've upgraded our Laravel application from Laravel 5.2 to 5.3 and got a warning message from Laravel side

> The Query Builder returns collections, instead of plain arrays, in
>   Laravel 5.3. You will need to upgrade your code to use collections or
>   chain the all() method onto your query to return a plain array.
>
> Thats means fluent query builder now returns
>   **Illuminate\Support\Collection instances instead of plain arrays**. This
>   brings consistency to the result types returned by the fluent query
>   builder and Eloquent.

You can standard this by below example

Laravel 5.2

```
    $users = DB::table('users')->select('id','first_name')->limit(10)->get();

   dd($users);

   Result : 
   ==========
    array:10 [▼
      0 => {#1423 ▼
        +"id": 12
        +"first_name": "John"
      }
      1 => {#1424 ▶}
      2 => {#1425 ▶}
      3 => {#1426 ▶}
      4 => {#1427 ▶}
      5 => {#1428 ▶}
      6 => {#1429 ▶}
      7 => {#1430 ▶}
      8 => {#1431 ▶}
      9 => {#1432 ▶}
    ]
```

Laravel 5.3

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('id','first_name')->limit(10)->get();

dd($users);



 Result : 
   ==========
    Collection {#1428 ▼
      #items: array:10 [▼
        0 => {#1430 ▼
          +"id": 12
          +"first_name": "John"
        }
        1 => {#1431 ▶}
        2 => {#1432 ▶}
        3 => {#1433 ▶}
        4 => {#1434 ▶}
        5 => {#1435 ▶}
        6 => {#1436 ▶}
        7 => {#1437 ▶}
        8 => {#1438 ▶}
        9 => {#1439 ▶}
      ]
    }
```

When I am trying to access data by `$users[0]->first_name` getting same result thats is correct.

That creates confusion for me.. What is the actual difference here and what will be the impact on our application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was worried about Array and Collection elements and lastly i know

> That Collection class holds the collection elements in a protected
>   property called $items (as you could see from your dump protected
>   'items' =>), which is of type array. The class also implements an
>   interface called IteratorAggregate, which basically means it allows
>   any variable of that type to be iterated using a foreach statement.

So in short `Collection` is an iterable object that can be treated as an array, but is better than an array because if offers extra methods that allow you to manipulate the items from the collection. You can check the Collection API to see a complete list of available methods.

Ref : [In a Laravel 5 Collection how do you return an array of objects instead of an array of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776849/in-a-laravel-5-collection-how-do-you-return-an-array-of-objects-instead-of-an-ar)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel collections implement "Arrayable" which means they inherit all of the same functionality as normal arrays but also have the additional functionality that collections provide, so you will not get any issues accessing at index.

If you want to convert it back to a normal array, you could do `->toArray()`

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('id','first_name')->limit(10)->get()->toArray();
```